# how to process output of groupByKey RDD which is key and list of Values RDD[K,List[v]]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to Spark and below issue bothering me for a while.

My input file is comma separated file and have created RDD which has Store as key and list of promotions as value. A key(my case product) can have more than one value.
I have grouped the RDD using GroupByKey. It solve my problem to bring all the promotions which comes under under same key. Upto this everything fine. Now I want to iterate through the list of value for each key to find out whether my key (store) is having particular promotion or not . If my key find that promotion then write the record with store(key) and promotion(value)

```
val firstRDD = sc.textFile(".....")
val secondRDD = firstRDD.map(line=>line.split(",")(0),line.split(",")(1))
val thirdRDD = secondRDD.groupByKey()

(1,(aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd))
(2,(aaa,ccc))
(3,(ddd,aaa))
```

based on above list I wanted to know for key 1 value aaa is exist or not if not aaa whether bbb is exist or not.. How to do this in Spark Scala.

Comment: Think about it as a basic Scala operation before using map. If you have a tuple how would you process it to get what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Because your RDD is of type Tuple2, you can use the PairRDD functionality. This means you have access to the "lookup" function of your RDDs. In order to see if `1` has a corresponding value of `aaa`, the easiest way would probably be

```
secondRDD.lookup(1).contains("aaa")
```

Note that it is easier to use secondRDD as opposed to thirdRDD for this.

Comment: thanks for your help... in my example my secondRDD key will not have all the values belongs to that. only after the groupByKey(), i will get List of value for that key.

Comment: val purchaseRDD = sc.textFile("sales.txt")

val purchaseRDDMap = purchaseRDD.map{purchase=> val fields = purchase.split(",")
      val purchaseKey = fields(0)
      val purchaseValue = fields(2).toDouble
     (purchaseKey,purchaseValue)
         }
    .groupByKey()
    .map(purchase=> (purchase._1, (purchase._2 ***after this i got stuck up